# build.gradle dependencies: fileTree vs. project vs. plain string

Tags: java, android, react-redux

I happen to be a JS developer learning RN.

I was building an app on RN using mapbox.

In the configuration, I stumbled upon `build.gradle`.

I googled about `build.gradle` to know that prupose is to specify library and module build configuration? (Is this correct?)

I was going through installation notes and I saw something like this (we need to change in configuration if our RN < 0.60)

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
+   implementation project(':@react-native-mapbox-gl_maps')
}
```

In dependencies I see they have implementation written in three different type

1. Using com
   `com.android.support:appcompat-v7`
2. Using Project
   `implementation project(':@react-native-mapbox-gl_maps')`

and

3. using fileTree

`fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])`

I tried to google something like difference between project and com in implementation in build.gradle but wasn't able to find anything useful.

Can someone help me educate with difference between the above dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's Remote binary dependency. Example when you push your library to some cloud repository (Google, JCenter ...)
2. It's Local library module dependency. When your project has some modules in your app like authentication module, view module. It's available on your project and you can edit the source of it.
3. It's Local binary dependency. When you want to share some internal library and don't publish to any cloud repository. You have to attach file .jar or .aar to the lib directory and link to it by finding it in "libs" directory.

More detail you can find [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency-types)